# Conditionally format in a word based on the value of other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I am attempting to format a cell with text based on the value of other cells.

[image]

What I would like to accomplish is for the word **"complete"** to appear in the cells of column E when the corresponding cells (F:J) in the same row are populated, meaning if they have any content in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a combination if the AND function and IF statement:

In your case, you would put this formula in E2:

```
=IF(AND(F2<>'',G2<>'',H2<>'',I2<>'',J2<>''),"complete","not complete")
```

The AND function lets you have many conditions to evaluate at one time, if they are all true then it will trigger the IF statement to display whatever is in the IFTRUE spot, and if not then whatever is in the IFNOT spot.

You signify a cell is filled out by not being blank so

```
F2 <> ''
```